# Get email and profile´s image with iOS Facebook-SDK 3.1

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

Recently I started my adventure of my apps integration with facebook-sdk.

I have an application that provides login with Facebook.
Thus the idea, after creating a session with facebook, is to get some data from the user and create a new one on my server with some data,

- Name
- Image URL
- email
- facebookID

Thus, I am using the latest version, [facebook sdk-3.1](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/).
I created a session with the permissions of the user to get the email.

```
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_location",
                        @"email",
                        nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];
```

The session is successfully created, after that I start creating user.

```
 if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {

                 self.userData.firstNameUser=user.name;
                 self.userData.lastNameUser=user.last_name;
                 self.userData.mainLocation=user.location.name;
                 self.userData.urlImageUser=user.link;
             }
         }];   
    }
```

So, how can i get the other data, **email** and **image´s Profile**, of the user using the last SDK, to sent to my server?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have user's profile image in user object itself.

Just create the object of FBProfilePictureView  set the object's ProfileID property.

e.g.

```
FBProfilePictureView *profileImage = [[FBProfilePictureView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
profileImage.profileID = user.id;
```

It will show user's profile image .

You can add the following code in your handler response .

Answer (score 0):

It works. Just add

```
[self.view addSubview:profileImage];
```